Gravitational time dilation – clock falling to event horizon
Given probe that falls into BH (simple non-moving mass M) staring from distance r=D, velocity v=0 and clock t=0, what will the clock show when entering the EH (or in general as function of the distance from the BH)?
I found (e.g. in wiki) formulas for objects not moving and with circular orbits but not for one falling straight to the BH.
I heard that it would take finite time for the probe to cross the EH but infinite when measured by distant observer (never saw a calculation).
Thanks

You can fall into the EH in finite proper time but not in finite coordinate time. You can hit the EH, essentially, but nobody watching at great distance behind you could see it happen. Try and draw a lightlike curve leading from some finite distance from the EH to an event on the EH, and see that you cannot do so without that event being at $t\to\infty$

Since you're asking what the clock itself will show, if you fall from rest the proper time $\rm \tau$ from $\rm r_0$ to $\rm r$ is the same as under Newton since in this case $\rm d^2r/d\tau^2=-GM/r^2$ just like with Newton:
$$\rm c \tau = \frac{r_0^{3/2} arctan \left(\sqrt{r_0/r-1}\right)}{\sqrt{r_s}}+\frac{r \ r_0 \sqrt{r_s/r-r_s/r_0}}{r_s}$$
The coordinate time measured by the far away bookkeeper goes to $\rm t \to \infty$ as $\rm r \to r_s$:
$$\rm c t = \frac{r \ r_0 \sqrt{1-r_s/r_0} \sqrt{r_s/r-r_s/r_0}}{r_s}+$$
$$\rm+r_s \sqrt{\frac{r_0}{r_s}-1} \left(\frac{r_0}{r_s}+r_s\right)  \ arctan \left(\sqrt{\frac{r_0}{r}-1}\right)+$$
$$\rm+2 r_s \ arctanh \left(\frac{\sqrt{r_s/r-r_s/r_0}}{\sqrt{1-r_s/r_0}}\right)$$
On the plot below $\rm \tau$ is red and $\rm t$ is blue, $\rm r$ is on the $\rm x$ axis:


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
